# Difference between obj-m+=[modules_list] and obj-m=[modules_list]

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

What's a difference between `obj-m=md1.o md2.o` and `obj-m+=md1.o md2.o` in a kernel make-file?

Comment: -1, because it is documented in [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html), so "your question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 3):

You can try to infer it with an example:

```
obj-m= a.o b.o
obj-m1= 1 2 3
obj-m= c.o d.o
obj-m1+= 4 5 6

ALL :
    echo $(obj-m) -- $(obj-m1)
```

Its output is

```
c.o d.o -- 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So: `=` assigns (overwriting), and `+=` appends.

Comment: You could also read it in [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/), there is an entire chapter about [Using variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html)